# Mongoose : how to set a field of a model with result from an agregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my sample :

Two simple Mongoose models:

- a Note model, with among other fields an id field that is a ref for the Notebook model.
- a Notebook model, with the id I mentioned above.

My goal is to output something like that:

```
[
  {
    "notes_count": 7,
    "title": "first notebook",
    "id": "5585a9ffc9506e64192858c1"
  },
  {
    "notes_count": 3,
    "title": "second notebook",
    "id": "558ab637cab9a2b01dae9a97"
  }
]
```

Using aggregation and population on the Note model like this :

```
Note.aggregate(
    [{
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$notebook",
            "notes_count": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    }, {
        "$project": {
            "notebook": "$_id",
            "notes_count": "$notes_count",
        }
    }]
```

gives me this kind of result :

```
{
  "_id": "5585a9ffc9506e64192858c1",
  "notes_count": 7,
  "notebook": {
    "_id": "5585a9ffc9506e64192858c1",
    "title": "un carnet court",
    "__v": 0
  }
}
```

Forget about __v and _id fields, would be easy to handle with a modified toJSON function.

But in this function neither doc nor ret params gives me access to the computed notes_count value.

Obviously, I could manage this in the route handler (parse result and recreate the datas that will be returned) but, is there a proper way to do that with mongoose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the aggregate method to update. As you have noted, you'll need to use output from the aggregate constructor to update the relevant documents.

As the Mongoose aggregate method will return a collection of plain objects, you can iterate through this and utilise the `_id` field (or similar) to update the documents.